# customizing directive to restrict the user to input special characters: angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive, special-characters

I am learning in detail about angularJs directive . Currently I am using it to restrict the user not to input special characters.

here is the code

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" no-special-char ng-model="vm.customTag" class="form-control" value="" />
```

**AngularJS Directive**

```
app.directive('noSpecialChar', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                if (inputValue == null)
                    return ''
                cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
                if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return cleanInputValue;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

here are two things which I want

(1)  user can input minus/dash `'-'` which is not happening right now, how can I change my `/[^\w\s]/gi` which allow the user to input - (dash/minus) sign as well.

(2)  The above functionality only restricts the user not to enter any special character, but when user types a special character I want to display a red alert as well **"special characters are not allowed"**, how can I do that ??

Any help is appreciated !!!

Thanks

Comment: but the replace code should remove all the special characters.. explain about the chars which comes under special chars.

Comment: I don't want user to input  ~ !@#$%^&*(){}[]?/+=,*`, it should be alpha numeric + minus(-) + _ (underscore) sign allowed

Comment: Have a look into angular forms validation. I would recommend marking the input as invalid and letting forms validation handle displaying the error. Also I wouldn't recommend changing what the user inputs, it is better to tell them they are doing something wrong rather than magically changing what they do.

Comment: 1) `/[^\w\s-]/gi`. 2) Use additional check like `if (/[^\w\s-]/.test(inputValue)) { /* Show the error in some control */ }`.

Answer (score 0):

**Question #1**

Currently, your RegEx is selecting all characters that are not (`[^`) a word character (`\w`) or whitespace (`\s`). To include a `-`, it needs to be included in the list of characters to not be replaced.

Try the following RegEx:

```
/[^\w\s-]/gi
```

To exclude any other characters from being removed, just add them after the `-`

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d44j)</kbd>

---

**Question #2**

You need to listen for the `keypress` event on the form, to see each time the content changes. You can then use `.match()` to see if any special characters exist. If they do, it will return a string which is `truthy`, if not it will return `false`.

You can check result of the `.match()` in an `if` statement, and if a special character is matched, add your message.

```
if (inputValue.match(/[^\w\s]/gi)) {
    // Add Alert Here!
}
```

Alternatively, inside your `if (cleanInputValue != inputValue)`, you could add the code to create the alert. Your `if` statement basically gives you the same outcome as the `.match()` method. It detects whether the string has been changed by the `.replace()` and runs the code inside if it has

Comment: that is what I am looking for Question 2, how can I add alert (bootstrap alert) inside directive, so that even if I have 100 text boxes I can reuse it just by attaching the name of directive as an attribute to input box

Answer (score 0):

**Edited further to comments:**

This does what you describe, not in a particularly "Angular" way - but achieves your described desired result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="ns.test">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303590/customizing-directive-to-restrict-the-user-to-input-special-characters-angular -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .input {
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 50px;
        }

            .input input {
                border: solid 1px black;
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-size: larger;
                padding: 5px;
            }

        .err {
            color: red;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 10px;
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-size: larger;
            display:inline;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module('ns.test', []);

        app.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.item = 'item1';
            $scope.item2 = 'item2';
            $scope.item3 = 'item3';
            $('input:first').focus();
        });

        var noSpecialChar = function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: '?ngModel',
                link: function (scope, elm, attr, modelCtrl) {
                    if (!modelCtrl) return;

                    modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                        if (inputValue == null)
                            return ''

                        var parent = $(elm).parent();

                        cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^a-z0-9-_]+/gi, '');
                        if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
                            if (parent.find(".err").length == 0)
                                parent.append("<div class=\"err\">Invalid Characters</div>"); // change the class here to your bootstrap alert classes
                        } else
                            parent.find(".err").remove();

                        return cleanInputValue;
                    });
                }
            };
        };

        app.directive('noSpecialChar', noSpecialChar);

    </script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="testController">
    <form name="userForm" novalidate>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" data-no-special-char data-ng-model="item" />
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" data-no-special-char data-ng-model="item2" />
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" data-no-special-char data-ng-model="item3" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but i dont want to use ng-pattern, because consider I have 100 text boxes in my application at different-2 places , Again I have to add this html stuff to text box which I dont want, what I am looking for is I want to have red alert box showing error which is implemented inside directive

Comment: I am looking for a custom directive there by which I can add this directive name as an attribute to n number of text boxes.

Comment: @shreyansh updated - let me know if that's what you're after.